# Regression analysis with 1 dependent and 1 independent variable

Tags: regression

Is it possible to have a regression analysis with 1 dependent and only 1 independent variable?

Comment: If you think of [simple linear regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression), then yes :-)

Comment: @chl is correct. If you'd like a simpler introduction to simple linear regression than the one in Wikipedia, I wrote one on [my blog](http://www.statisticalanalysisconsulting.com/54/)

Comment: Funny, a long time ago, when I was just out of high school, it took me some training to realize that I can use *more than one* independent variable in a regression model :-)

Answer (score 4):

The Answer is YES, it is possible using **Simple Linear Regression**.

Please refer this [link](http://www.maths-statistics-tutor.com/simple_linear_regression_pasw_spss.php) to know how to perform this analysis in SPSS.

You can also do this analysis in MS Excel if you do not have SPSS. Please refer this [link](http://www.unf.edu/~dtanner/dtch/dt_ch6.htm)

I think by now you might be familiar with simple linear regression but I'm writing this answer just because I hope the other new members to this topic could find this useful.

Comment: If any statistical software can't do this, then it doesn't qualify as statistical software.